# Windows Phone SDK 8.0 XAML Designer not loading

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

**Before negative reporting, first figure out how this question is different from other designer loading problem. Look at their exceptions and mine.**

Designer was working fine, I don't know what happened suddenly.

NOTE: I've tried uninstalling and re-installing. I've done with all VS12 update. Still facing designer issue.

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Metadata.PlatformMetadataBase.GetPlatformAssemblies()
   at Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightPlatformMetadata..ctor(IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver platformRuntimeAssemblyResolver, IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver platformReferenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightPlatform..ctor(IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver platformRuntimeAssemblyResolver, IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver platformReferenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.Expression.WindowsPhonePlatform.MobilePlatform..ctor(IPlatformRuntimeAssemblyResolver platformRuntimeAssemblyResolver, IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver platformReferenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.Expression.WindowsPhonePlatform.WindowsPhonePlatformCreator.CreatePlatformInternal(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextBase.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.XamlProjectContext.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__f(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__e()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.<MarshalIn>b__15()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass8.<CreateDesignerImpl>b__6(IRemoteDesignerService d)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.<MarshalOut>b__3()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__11(RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`2 func)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

And I've tried uninstalling and re-installing all Silverlight SDKs. So please, some useful answers needed!

Comment: Can you use the designer in a new project without any problems?

Comment: No. Designer doesn't load at all.

Comment: On the other hand, Windows Store's XAML designer loads perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is solved. I just re-installed my whole Operating System and pikatch!

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestion [here](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/08/visual-studio-designer-not-working-nullreferenceexception-in-windows-phone-solution-after-wp8-sdk-installation/) (in the same order)

> 1: Uninstall WP8 SDK
>
> 2: Uninstall all instances of Silverlight SDK and
> Rutime.
>
> 3: Re-install WP8 SDK.
>
> I used it in the following workflow and it fixed my designer problem:
>
> 1: Uninstalled all WP7 SDK:s
>
> 2: Restarted computer (The designer still
> failed after this step)
>
> 3: Uninstalled WP8 SDK (Maybe it is enough to
> choose repair here, but I selected to uninstall the SDK)
>
> 4: Restarted
> computer
>
> 5: Installed the WP8 SDK

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried this approach, nothing happened!

Comment: You mentioned that you uninstalled Silverlight SDKs (not WP8 SDK) and not in any particular order. This may have made a difference.

Comment: Of-coursetopic is related to WP then it will be WP SDK, not Android for God sake.

Comment: Calm down. You do realise there's a difference between the Silverlight SDK and Windows Phone SDK? Don't see Android being mentioned anywhere....

Comment: Don't take it personally brother.